# Как установить расширение php на сервер

Tags: php

Подскажите как правильно  установить расширение php пошагово ?
 к примеру   на сервере не хватает расширения ZipArchive мануал http://php.net/manual/ru/book.zip.php

```
нагуглил несколько вариантов 
sudo apt-get install php7.1-zip выбивает ошибку 
yum install php7.1-zip -- чтото установилось но не работает
```

возможно нужно еще какие-то действия помогите разобраться?

```
Сервер 
PHP Version 7.1.16
System  Linux server.domain.com 4.16.1-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Apr 8 10:21:51 EDT 2018 x86_64
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
```

Comment: Вы бы сперва рассказали, что за сервер хоть

Comment: И что значит __не работает__

Comment: --u_mulder -- ошибка : sudo: apt-get: command not found

Comment: -- andreymal- добавил в описание

Comment: Что-то ваша информация о сервере не дала никакой информации. Дистрибутив-то какой? root-доступ вообще есть? shared-хостинг, VPS/VDS/выделенный?

Comment: Так, значит это не ubuntu/debian. Yum у нас в `CentOS`. Телепатия - __сила__. Далее - что значит "чтото установилось но не работает"? Какие предприняты действия для выяснения что не работает?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесник т.к. я вижу el в названии пакета - у вас либо RedHat либо CentOS , соответвенно нужно использовать yum , apt-get - это Ubuntu и Debian

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесник опишите проблему полностью, зачем вам нужен этот модуль, где вы его используете, какие ошибки возникают при использовании и какой ожидаемый результат

Comment: @ Ivan Ignatiev - MSFT мне нужно использовать библиотеку   $zip = new \ZipArchive; локально у меня было все ок ,но на сервере  беда
ошибка говорит что класса такого не существует , а локально все хорошо

Comment: @ andreymal -- root доступы да есть

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесник после установки расширения с помощью yum, вы перезагружали веб-сервер или сервис php-fpm ?

Comment: @– Ivan Ignatiev - MSFT  нет не перезагружал, вернее я пытался перезагрузить но также сыпались ошибки ,подскажите как правильно перезагрузить сервер ? я попробую выполнить

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесник с пользователем root в вашем случаее скорее всего 
 команда service apache2 restart или команда service httpd restart

Comment: перезагрузка к сожалению не помогла

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесник возможно вам нужно раскомментировать extentions=php_zip.so в php.ini и потом еще раз перезагрузить сервис веб-сервера,  выложите результат странички  с кодом phpinfo, чтобы проверить какие модули были загружены: <?php
 phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);

Answer (score 0):

команды Linux которые я выполнил для установки возможно кому то пригодятся

```
yum install php-zip --enablerepo=remi-php71
cat /etc/redhat-release
rpm -qa | grep php
yum install php71-php-zip --enablerepo=remi
php -m
service httpd restart
```